# Do I need to re-migrate/import my EF tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, sql-server-2019

My current project is an E-Commerce API. The database I am reading from is from Microsoft Dynamics GP. The database is currently hosted on everything from SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2019. I cannot modify the schema. We have many different projects, all reading and writing to this same database.

I have done everything I can find to increase my API's speed. I have even cheated a few times and created a few indexes or two. With the last combined patch (CU13) for SQL Server 2019, I ran SQL Server profiler and started a script that benchmarks all the heavy queries. I then ran the Tuning Wizard against the trace log. It recommended half a page of new indexes which I implemented.

Now, since I am using Entity Framework Core and I initially migrated / imported the tables I needed, do I need to re-import my tables to take advantage of the recently created indexes? Or will they automatically be used by the SQL Server regardless if EF knows about them or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They will automatically be used by the SQL Server regardless if EF knows about them or not.